# Get Key value pairs from below object using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am learning javascript and this may be a basic question, please help me to acheive below.

I am constructing an array inside obejct like below to use data later. Now, i have to send category as "Help" and need to get all it's subcategory values dynamically.

```
 [
    {"category":"Help","subcategory":"Email"},
    {"category":"Help","subcategory":"application"},
    {"category":"Help","subcategory":"Software"},
    {"category":"Help","subcategory":"Hardware"},
    {"category":"Request","subcategory":"Access"},
    {"category":"Request","subcategory":"Remote"},
    ]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could filter with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) first and then get the values with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var array = [{ category: "Help", subcategory: "Email" }, { category: "Help", subcategory: "application" }, { category: "Help", subcategory: "Software" }, { category: "Help", subcategory: "Hardware" }, { category: "Request", subcategory: "Access" }, { category: "Request", subcategory: "Remote" }],
    subcategory = array
        .filter(a => a.category === 'Help')
        .map(a => a.subcategory);
    
console.log(subcategory);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES5

```js
var array = [{ category: "Help", subcategory: "Email" }, { category: "Help", subcategory: "application" }, { category: "Help", subcategory: "Software" }, { category: "Help", subcategory: "Hardware" }, { category: "Request", subcategory: "Access" }, { category: "Request", subcategory: "Remote" }],
    subcategory = array
        .filter(function (a) { return a.category === 'Help'; })
        .map(function (a) { return a.subcategory; });
    
console.log(subcategory);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `filter` method in order to achieve this.

Also, use `map` method in order to create a new array only with the `subcategories`.

```js
var array=[
    {"category":"Help","subcategory":"Email"},
    {"category":"Help","subcategory":"application"},
    {"category":"Help","subcategory":"Software"},
    {"category":"Help","subcategory":"Hardware"},
    {"category":"Request","subcategory":"Access"},
    {"category":"Request","subcategory":"Remote"},
];

var subcategories = array.filter(a => a.category === "Help").map(a => a.subcategory);
console.log(subcategories);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi Mihai, Thank you !! when i try to run the above script in browser console i am getting below error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>". I will be really greatful if you can give me the steps to do it in detail